# How to call methods on contract member objects from javavascript?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I want to call a method on a contract that is member of another contract from javascript.

```
contract Dog {
  function bark() returns (memory string) {
    return "woof";
  }
}

contract Human {
  Dog public myDog = new Dog();
}
```

from ethers.js

```
const sound = await humanContract.myDog.bark(); // How to do this?
```